# Injecting mock into a class for each test(Junit4)

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have the following example test class

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class EdgeClusterTest {

    @Mock
    ClusterStore clusterStore;

    @Mock
    TaskClientIntf taskClient;

    @InjectMocks
    EdgeClusterHandler clusterHandler;


    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void invalidClusterId() {
        clusterHandler = new EdgeClusterHandler();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        clusterHandler.getClusterInfo("..u2","5");
    }
```

The first 2 lines inside my test are

```
        clusterHandler = new EdgeClusterHandler();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

While in this trivial example, my class does not take constructors and I can move the init logic inside a function annotated with `@Before`. But say my class will support 3 different types of constructors. I want to create a fresh instance based on the test and use appropriate constructor and also inject the mocks into this new instance.

The above way is the only way? Is there any other cleaner way of doing it?